# How to edit the shape of pads for a component footprint in Fusion 360?

Tags: eaglecad

Using Fusion 360, I'm attempting to create a PCB component that has irregularly shaped pads (see image). The 45deg pads in each corner are essential, otherwise the nets will short.

In my electronics library, I have successfully created a package using the 3d package generator. I then switch to the footprint view, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to modify the shape of the corner pads.

How can I modify the shape of these pads?

[image: pad specification]

[image: footprint]

Comment: Could you just forget the chamfers and simply shorten the pads?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to, the pads are in the wrong spot. Check the datasheet again and use the pad recommendations (if any). If those can't be found then find the industry standard part (or look elsewhere on the manufacturers site or contact them directly about footprint information). It's not likely that a PCB manufacturer would be able to put a chamfer (that appears to be under 3mil) as most have a lower resolution around that size for standard manufacturing.

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge, for now you can't directly.
The pad command currently only supports rectangular shapes with radio on the edge.

But there as some workarounds.

1. If it is only for hobby projects, for this footprint also a shorter pad for this position will work (for professional projects reliability and DFM could be an issue).
2. You can put a mini pad in the position of the pad. Then you can draw the desired pad shape with the polygon command and give it the same name as the pad - be aware that when you use this method, you have to also draw the polygon on tCream (solderpaste opening) and tStop (soldermask opening) layer.
   For detail explanation of each layer, pleas check: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/every-layer-explained-autodesk-eagle/

Regarding question for Fusion360, I'd also ask them in the https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/fusion-360/ct-p/1234
This forum is frequently moderated by Autodesk employees / experts who give you at times answers / solutions that are not commonly known.